# how to remove warning variant.getMergeResources() warning

Tags: android, gradle

I get a warning when I build my android project.

```
 WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
Affected Modules: app
```

Here is my Project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.41"
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is my App level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 60
        versionName "0.6.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", apkFileName)

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file("path/to/keystore/file")
                storePassword "Actual Password here"
                keyAlias "Actual Alias here"
                keyPassword "Actual Password here"
            }
        }
        kapt {
            arguments {
                arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
            }
        }


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        flavorDimensions "default"

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    testOptions {
        execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
            dimension "default"
        }
        stage {
            applicationIdSuffix ".stage"
            versionNameSuffix "-stage"
            dimension "default"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "default"
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1"
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0-beta02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0-beta02'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.40"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //DependencyInjection
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16'

    //RxJava2
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.19.0'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0'

    //Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.41"

    //nearby
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0'

    //test
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'

    //kotlin
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'

    //location
    implementation 'com.patloew.rxlocation:rxlocation:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'

    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.4'
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1"
    compileOnly 'com.squareup.inject:assisted-inject-annotations-dagger2:0.3.2'
    kapt 'com.squareup.inject:assisted-inject-processor-dagger2:0.3.2'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0"

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-offline-v7:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation group: 'com.cloudinary', name: 'cloudinary-android', version: '1.24.0'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried following some answers on SO and got to a log that didn't reveal much.

I tried following some common answers on SO, and I got this long log. 
tho I don't understand what is the library causing the issue.

Here is the log:

```
    WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
REASON: It is currently called from the following trace:
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.DeprecationReporterImpl.reportDeprecatedApi(DeprecationReporterImpl.kt:79)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantImpl.getMergeResources(BaseVariantImpl.java:349)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated.getMergeResources(null:-1)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty.getProperty(MetaBeanProperty.java:59)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:228)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:171)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:55)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:59)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated.getProperty(null:-1)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:298)
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.handleVariant(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:164)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:78)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:398)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:338)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:176)
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$_setupPlugin_closure5.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:110)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:70)
org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithFewActions.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:285)
org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:247)
org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:236)
com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.addVariant(AppExtension.java:87)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:134)
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:772)
com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$4(BasePlugin.java:646)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:37)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:-1)
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:150)
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:58)
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:147)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:144)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.afterEvaluate(null:-1)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:190)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:187)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.stepEvaluationListener(DefaultProject.java:1419)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:196)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:111)
org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:226)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:220)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:95)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:693)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:141)
org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:302)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:210)
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle files. Also try to run `gradlew sync -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true` and get the log.

Comment: Thanks. I added them both.

Comment: it seems that `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0` is using `variant.mergeResources`

Comment: Hi @GabrieleMariotti, could you share how did you narrow down to com.google.gms:google-services?

Answer (score 0):

change build.gradle **Project**

```
dependencies {
    //return build:gradle version to 3.2.1
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

and Sync

Comment: is downgrading the Gradle version safe? I would rather keep going forward instead of downgrading.

Comment: No, no harm
And there is no way to reduce the version until the general update by the developer team